# Extend UIViewController to implement tableView(_ tableView: willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I want to change the design of cells of a `ViewController` i don't own. So my Idea was an extension like this:

```
extension NotMyViewController {
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "DesignersChoice", size: 12)
    }
}
```

but this function is never called. Any Ideas how to make our designer happy?

Comment: What do you mean by "i don't own"? how do you talk to the ViewController?

Comment: Check tableView `delegate`

Answer (score 0):

Confirm your class to `UITableViewDelegate` protocol

```
extension NotMyViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "DesignersChoice", size: 12)
    }
}
```

also make NotMyViewController as delegate for your tableView

Answer (score -1):

Use `cellForRowAtIndex` method. In that method write below line:-

```
cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "DesignersChoice", size: 12)
```